# Best Practice For updating Target Table In Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powerexchange

what is the best way to implement an update into the target table ?:

-using update strategy in designer part
OR using Update Method in Session Properties

Answer (score 1):

I should use update strategy. There are some differences and some similarities.
Similarities -

1. Performance - Identical performance. The Index(s) on the target matters in case of update.
2. Define Key columns in Target. You have to do this for both strategies.

But there are some differences which gives more power to Update strategy -

1. Flexibility - You can create logic for insert,update, delete,ignore.
2. Future usage - An update strategy can be used to implement any logic in future.

Alternately, update in session property will give you a cleaner session log but thats all :)